# How can I send/generate traffic in GCP?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc-peering

I'm using GCP for building a simple scenario.
I set 3 VMs in deferent locations in a default VPC. I would like to send/generate traffic in order to use VPC flow logs, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What kind of traffic?

Comment: @MichaelHampton HTTP/SSL/UDP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply setup a [basic web server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache) in one the GCP VM instances and then run the [curl tool](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1145-how-to-send-http-requests-using-curl) from the client to generate HTTP/HTTPS request to the server. Similarly, you can use Netcat tool to send TCP/UDP traffic from the client to the server.

More details in regards to sending UDP traffic between server and client can be found in [here](https://help.ubidots.com/developer-guides/sending-tcpudp-packets-using-netcat).